# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext automaticlly getting closed, Debug logs not showing any exception

Tags: netty, spring-rabbit

**My spring application on the netty server is getting automatically closed in 10 min after starting. I changed the log from 'info' to Debug but the logs are not showing any exception. I am trying but feel stuck. Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks**

**Following is the log snippet...**

15:15:02.450 [anLyticsListenerContainer-32] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - **Retrieving delivery for Consumer: t**ags=[{amq.ctag-qBQuL4lTZX29dijvWbPu-g=ot.admin.benchmark.data.replay.notify}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://app@XXXXXX:5672/,31), conn: Proxy@7abece2b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@5c1b07a8 [delegate=amqp://app@XXXXXX:5672/, localPort= 42744], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

15:15:02.450 [anLyticsListenerContainer-39] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-OsOCBFLyuSfC_llybmELg=ot.admin.benchmark.data.replay.notify}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://app@XXXXX:5672/,25), conn: Proxy@7abece2b Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@5c1b07a8 [delegate=amqp://app@XXXXX:5672/, localPort= 42744], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0

15:15:03.112 [Thread-5] INFO  **o.s.c.s.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext**@417009d9: startup date [Wed Apr 01 15:07:14 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy

15:15:03.112 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'

15:15:03.113 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 
'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerEndpointRegistry'

15:15:03.114 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectionFactory'

15:15:03.114 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'benchmarkUserDocumentUploadListenerContainer'
......
.....
15:15:03.114 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'

15:15:03.114 [Thread-5] INFO  o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 2147483647

15:15:03.114 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.c.s.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Asking bean 'benchmarkUserDocumentUploadListenerContainer' of type [class org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] to stop

15:15:03.115 [Thread-5] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Shutting down Rabbit listener container
15:15:03.122 [Thread-6] INFO  com.ot.netty.NettyHttpServer - [OT-API-server] Shutting down ...

15:15:03.122 [pool-2-thread-5] DEBUG o.s.a.r.l.BlockingQueueConsumer - **Received cancelOk for tag amq.ctag-H**_cNz1VPI6375r6X4o0nIQ (ot.admin.benchmark.s3.user); Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-H_cNz1VPI6375r6X4o0nIQ=ot.admin.benchmark.s3.user}],

Comment: What is `Thread-5` - the name is not familiar - probably yours? Run in a debugger and put a breakpoint in `AbstractApplicationContext.doClose()` to see what is triggering the close.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I checked that the same application works fine on local server. Let me see more as guided.

Comment: A quick diagnostic might be to subclass the application context, override `close()` and print a stack trace to see who's calling it.